# retrieve Number of days between order date and shipment date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Order table has order date and shipment date. I need to retrieve number of days between order date and shipment date.
for example: order date = 31/08/96
shipment date= 10/09/96 for oracle 11g.

Comment: Just subtract the two dates.  That will give you the number of days between the two.

Comment: for 3 records shipment date has null so when i subtract shipment date -order date. it display null.

Comment: subtract order date from coalesce(shipment date, sysdate) then

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract them, as e.g. in select date2 - date2 total_days from dual